# UV unwrapping - Why my unwrapped image is totally black?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I have more than one time now unwrapped an image and texture painted on directly from blender.

However, I would like to export the image to Photoshop or Corel draw to paint it there in a more detailed way.

When I tried to do so the image unwrapped and saved from blender turned only black.   I gave the image a fill in blender and saved it once again but still, it turned[image] black when I opened it.  I could not see the unwrapped edges of my model so I could not paint it.

How is texture painting done if you cannot see the lines?

Comment: In the UV editor, in edit mode, use the menu "UV/Export UV Layout".